# How to send dynamic request type using axios in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have this small query

I have a custom axios instance

```js
/* api.js */
import axios from 'axios';

// base axios instance
export default axios.create({
  baseURL: `http://localhost:8888`,
});
```

When i use it in a function where I am sending `request method` as an argument:

```js
import api from '../api.js';
// passing method = "GET"
// URL = "/ai-metrics/<id>"
const someFunction = async (method, url) => {
  await api[method](url);
}
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.default[method] is not a function
```

This works when I specify the axios method manually:

```
await api.GET(<url>) // this works
```

Comment: Can you give a [mre] - what value are you passing as `method`? Have you checked the value of `api`? Also note you can use the general `request` method with an object containing the method: `.request({ url, method })`.

Comment: I'm surprised that works with uppercase at all, aren't the methods all lowercase?

Comment: Getting same error with both

Comment: Here is [almost your code](https://runkit.com/embed/3w01duv3kkn7) working. Try lowercase method names.

Comment: When I try it I see the same thing: works fine for lowercase method names whether using dot or bracket notation; fails with TypeError for uppercase method names whether using dot or bracket notation. That seems to be consistent between the tests (Jest, JSDOM environment, Babel) and in the browser (Weback dev server, Chrome/Firefox). I can't recreate the behaviour you describe in the question where it works with `thing.GET` but fails with `thing['GET']`.